# Mongomapper querying on 'belongs_to' model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongomapper

I have two models:

```
class Post
 include MongoMapper::Document

 many :comments

 key :content, String
end
```

and

```
class Comment
  include MongoMapper::Document

  belongs_to :post

  key :post_id, ObjectId
  key :content, String

end
```

in a rails console session I can find all Posts:

```
Post.all # -> [#<Post _id: BSON::ObjectId('519b0b613…
```

and all comments associated with a Post:

```
post = Post.first # -> #<Post _id: BSON::ObjectId('519b0b613e477b…
post.comments     # -> [#<Comment _id: BSON::ObjectId('519d14f93e…
```

however, the following query strangely returns an empty array

```
Comment.all # -> []
```

Why? How can I get a list of all comments independently of the posts?

Answer (score 0):

With models exactly as per your post, it works for me as shown in the the following test,
running rails (3.2.13), mongo_mapper (0.12.0), mongo (1.6.4).  Next time please post the full minimal script, you probably just have a simple error.

test/unit/post_test.rb

```
require 'test_helper'

class PostTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  def setup
    Post.delete_all
    Comment.delete_all
  end

  test "post and comment" do
    post = Post.create(:content => 'Twas brillig')
    comment = Comment.create(:post_id => post.id, :content => 'and the slythy toves')
    post.comments << comment
    assert_equal 1, Post.count
    assert_equal 1, Comment.count
    puts
    puts "all posts: #{Post.all.inspect}"
    puts "first post comments: #{Post.first.comments.inspect}"
    puts "all comments: #{Comment.all.inspect}"
  end
end
```

$ rake test

Run options:

```
# Running tests:

[1/1] PostTest#test_post_and_comment
all posts: [#<Post _id: BSON::ObjectId('51ddb56a7f11ba9bbf000001'), content: "Twas brillig">]
first post comments: [#<Comment _id: BSON::ObjectId('51ddb56a7f11ba9bbf000002'), content: "and the slythy toves", post_id: BSON::ObjectId('51ddb56a7f11ba9bbf000001')>]
all comments: [#<Comment _id: BSON::ObjectId('51ddb56a7f11ba9bbf000002'), content: "and the slythy toves", post_id: BSON::ObjectId('51ddb56a7f11ba9bbf000001')>]
Finished tests in 0.036030s, 27.7546 tests/s, 0.0000 assertions/s.
1 tests, 0 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips

ruby -v: ruby 2.0.0p195 (2013-05-14 revision 40734) [x86_64-darwin12.3.0]
```